# Sed command to delete characters on specific location?

Tags: shell, sed, txt

I have this sed command which add's 3 zero's to an id (this occurs only if the id is 13 characters long):

```
sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)\([0-9]\{13\}[^0-9]\)/\1000\2/' file
```

My input looks like this:

```
A:AAAA:AA: :A:**0123456789ABC   **:AAA:AAA       :          :AA:          :     :
```

And my output is this one:

```
A:AAAA:AA: :A:**0000123456789ABC   **:AAA:AAA       :          :AA:          :     :
```

I want to get rid off the 3 whitespaces after the id number. I can't delete the entire column because I have different data on other records so I want to delete the spaces just in the records/lines I expanded previously. So maybe I just need to add something to the existing command.
As you can see there are other whitespaces on the record, but I just want to delete the ones next to de ID(bold one).

I only found ways to delete entire columns, but I haven't been able to find a way to delete specific characters.

Comment: Try `sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)\([[:alnum:]]\{13\}\)[[:space:]]*:/\1000\2:/'`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, I can't upvote it nor mark it as the solution since is a comment but it helped a lot:)

Comment: Just added with a short explanation. I understand the whitespaces are always followed with a colon.

Comment: Use `awk` to manipulate just the 6th field as when the leading fields change in size, counting from the start of the string will fail. See my suggestion below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)\([[:alnum:]]\{13\}\)[[:space:]]*:/\1000\2:/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OGAd6L):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='A:AAAA:AA: :A:0123456789ABC   :AAA:AAA       :          :AA:          :     :'
sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)\([[:alnum:]]\{13\}\)[[:space:]]*:/\1000\2:/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
A:AAAA:AA: :A:0000123456789ABC:AAA:AAA       :          :AA:          :     :
```

Notes:

- `[[:alnum:]]\{13\}` - matches 13 *alphanumeric chars*, not just digits
- `[[:space:]]*:` matches zero or more whitespaces and a `:` (hence, the `:` must be added into the replacement pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Just add three spaces after the closing `\)`:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)\([0-9]\{13\}[^0-9]\)   /\1000\2/'
```

To make it work for your example, you also need to extend `[0-9]` to `[0-9A-C]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with delimited fields, when one of the fields before the one you are working with inevitably changes in size just counting from the start a fixed length will break this.

Consider using `awk` instead and work solely with the 6th field.  First strip out spaces, then check the length.  If 13, add the leading 3 zeroes.  Lastly print out the line.

```
$ awk -F ':' 'BEGIN { OFS=":"}{ gsub(" ", "", $6) };{if(length($6) == 13)$6="000"$6;print $0}' file.txt
A:AAAA:AA: :A:0000123456789ABC:AAA:AAA       :          :AA:          :     :
$
```